# htaccess friendly url hell

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been at this for a while but htaccess rewrite its's driving me to drink.  So I'm looking for somebody smarter than me.

I have a test site like so:

```
 www.domain.com/directory/index.php
```

But I'd like to use friendly url's.  So I'd like these to all go directly to index.php:

```
 www.domain.com/directory/
 www.domain.com/directory/index.php
 www.domain.com/directory/index.php/arg1/arg2/arg3/arg4
 www.domain.com/directory/calendar/arg1/arg2/arg3/arg4
 www.domain.com/directory/anything-here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules in the htaccess file in your `directory` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

How things get routed depends on the last line. If you want it passed as a parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

or if you want to use the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've had some problems with losing assets like css, images and jquery in subdirectories, will they work with this?  Honestly I've had so many failures it's ridiculous.  But I'll give it a try.

Comment: @user2070436 I'm guessing stuff like that is because of relative URL's in your page content. Try adding this to your page headers: `<base href="/" />` (or whatever the base should be, maybe `<base href="/directory/" />`?)

Comment: The base tag was a good idea.  It fixed that part of the problem  But if I try `www.domain.org/directory/test` then I get a server error page.  I'm using the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` line.

Comment: In fact, either one of the rewrite rules fails for some reason if I do this too `www.domain.org/directory/index.php/test`